# Python/math prime inquiry

Tags: python, math

Need help understanding the math used to conclude that a number is prime in lament terms. A detailed breakdown would be extremely helpful!

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and format the code into the post

Comment: so this second approach throws out all even numbers bigger than 2, since those will have 2 as a factor, as well as something else (besides 1). It also knows if it has not found a factor (other than 1) until it gets beyond the squareroot of the number, it will not find one (other than the number itself), because that would need to have a companion factor that was less than the squareroot of the number. But the basic logic is the code runs through possible factors, and if when it divides the number by them it gets a remainder of 0, it knows it found a factor, and so the number is not prime.

Comment: [It's better not to post pictures...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3180386)

Answer (score 1):

As follows:

```
if num % 2 == 0 and num > 2:
```

can be restated as - if your number is an even number and the number is greater than 2 it cannot be a prime number.  The `num % 2` [returns the remainder of the expression](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html).  So `5 % 2` => 1 whereas `4 % 2` => 0.  All even numbers will be divisible by 2 and therefore not prime - any number divisible by 2 that is less than 2 is not prime.

```
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)) +1, 2):
```

can be restated as picking number in a range that starts with 3 (the first integer >2), ending with the square root of the number your checking to see if it is a prime number (`num`) and `stepping` by 2.  The stepping by 2 means that it will skip all even numbers when starting at 3.  As a note ([reference](https://www.quora.com/If-a-number-n-is-not-divisible-from-2-to-square-root-of-n-then-it-is-said-to-be-prime-Why)), any `i` that is more than the square root of `num` WILL have a factor that is between 3 and the square root of your number - so you can stop generating numbers at that point.

```
if num % i == 0:
```

can be restated similar to testing for even numbers.  This will take the numbers from the range (the number `i`) and divide it into your number being tested.  If it can go into the number with no remainder, then the number isn't prime.  For both the if statements - if the number is evenly divided (results in a modulus of 0) then the code will `return False` meaning the number isn't prime.  If the number is not dividable by an even number and is not dividable by an odd number between 3 and the square root of the number then the code will `return True` - - meaning the number is prime.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: no problem - but you need to actually type your code into the browser - not just make the picture bigger...  :-)  if this answered your question you can accept it as the answer.